# Passing ArrayList<MyObject> Between multiple Activities

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I am trying to pass an ArrayList of Objects between multiple activities in my application. Is it possible to do this using an Intent using the setData() method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to send an ArrayList of  objects then your class must implement the [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) interface .

See these good tutorials for sending custom object between Activities

http://androidideasblog.blogspot.in/2010/02/passing-list-of-objects-between.html

http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/simple-tutorial-passing-arraylist-across-activities-t9996.html

Comment: The first link had clear enough instructions and a working example. Thanks.

Comment: Guys , I have problem I'm getting **TransactionTooLargeException** when I pass large Arraylist Using  Parcelable or Serializable . Need help on that.

Answer (score 6):

Use below code for pass arraylist in intent.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
mIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Data", mArraylist);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Use below code For get arraylist from Intent.

```
Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
mArraylist1 = bdl.getParcelableArrayList("Data");
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to extend parcelable class in your Object class. Then you can pass it through intent via `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("PASSING_DATA", data);`

here data is arraylist of custom objects.

see [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and [Parcelable Tutorial](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html) for better undertanding

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible...
You need to implement  **Serializable** class by your object class.

Answer (score 0):

If the objects implement Parcelable you can use the putParcelableArrayList method like this:

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putParcelableArrayList("myArrayList", myList);
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("data", data);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, it works if the objects in the ArrayList implement Parcelable.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the arraylist static where you are defining it, and only pass the position to the next activity