# How to pass object from one activity to another activity without using Intent

Tags: android, android-activity, interface

I am new at developing Android .I have a question. How to pass object from one activity to another activity without using Intent.Can I do it by Interface ,if so how  Could you please how can I hanle that

Comment: biggest question: Why not using Intent? "Pass" suggests that one activity starts the other. So why not using the intent you have to create anyway to start the second activity?

Comment: Why not use putExtra on an intent? :O

Comment: My main purpose is that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173535/android-listview-item-edit-operation

Comment: My main purpose is that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173535/android-listview-item-edit-operation 
I have 3 activity, MainActivity,ShowDetailAcivity,EditDetailAcivity
MainActivity has listview,when I clicked item on listview,ShowDetailAcivity is launched.Component visibles on ShowDetailAcivity are false.it is just for view.Then I clicked option menu item(Edit) on ShowDetailAcivity,EditDetailAcivity is launched and the user can change the values of Course object.After that updated value of object will transfer to Listview to MainAcivity.I have just only ArrayList on MainAcivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save data in a singleton class model and get the same object from another activity
Create a class like this

```
 public class SingletonModel {
     private static SingletonModel instance;
     public String textData = ""


     public synchronized  static SingletonModel getSingletonModel() {

         if (instance == null) {
             instance = new SingletonModel();
         }
         return instance;

     }

 private void SingletonModel(){}

 }
```

From first activity do like this

```
SingletonModel.getSingletonModel().textData ="Your data goes here";
```

From second activity do like this

```
 textView.setText(SingletonModel.getSingletonModel().textData);
```

Comment: also textData is private and can not be accessed through the `.` operator

Answer (score 2):

I think you have 2 options

1. In memory, save it to somewhere that all activities can reach, or make it static. This is not good idea though
2. Save it to disk, and use it, such as shared preferences

Answer (score 2):

- You can store it in SharedPreferences and then in another Activity
  restore it.
- You can store it in SQLite and then in another Activity restore it.
- You can use static links
- You can use service

Answer (score 1):

If the data should persist, use a file. If not, use a singleton.