# Kotlin pass array of custom objects via Intents and receive as a ArrayList

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I have a couple of activities and I pass data between them using Intents. I want to pass an array of my custom object from the first activity and make it an arraylist in the second activity. The code that I have is:

```
data class Attachment(val Name: String, val Content: String)

class ActivityA {
    private var attachments: Array<Attachment> = arrayOf()
    fun callB() {
        intent = Intent(this,ActivityB::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("Attachments", attachments)
        }
    }
}

class ActivityB {
    private var attachments: ArrayList<Attachment>?

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // How do I get the passed array and store in the arraylist here ?

        val a: Array<Attachment> = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("Attachments") as Array<Attachment>
        attachments = a // fails with a type mismatch error
        attachments = ArrayList(a) // fails again
        attachments = intent.get????????("Attachments") // any such option ?
    }
}
```

Now my question is, what is the most efficient way to get the `attachments` array in ActivityA to the `attachments` array-list in the ActivityB ?

Comment: All I know is that [your class must implement the `Parcelable` or `Serializable` interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13722113/4778343)

Comment: Yes, I too found that. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is simple.

```
data class Attachment(val Name: String, val Content: String) : Serializable

// In ActivityB
val a: Array<SecretJSON.Attachment> = intent.getSerializableExtra("Attachments") as Array<Attachment>
attachments = a.toCollection(ArrayList())
```